# Almost sure limit of a sequence

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I have a random variable $X$, which is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. The underlying probability space is as usual $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$. For every $t$ with $0\leq t < 1$, I define a random variable $$Y_t = \frac{1_{\{X > t\}}}{1-t}$$

I would like to find out what $\lim_{t\uparrow 1} Y_t$ is. I fix $\omega \in \Omega$. Then, I can say that a.s. $X(\omega) \in [0,1)$.

So then $1_{\{X(\omega) > t\}}(\omega) \to 0$ as $t\to 1$. But the denominator also goes to $0$. How do I determine this limit?

Comment: If all you knew was $1_{\{X(\omega) > t\}}(\omega) \to 0$ there would be a problem. But you know more than that. In fact $X<1$ almost surely, so almost surely there exists $r<1$ such that $1_{\{X(\omega) > t\}}(\omega) = 0$ for every $t\in(r,1)$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich So then the limit is 0?

Comment: Yes - that ratio _equals_ $1$ for all $t$ close enough to $1$, so the limit is $1$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I am confused. For $t$ close to 1, the limit  of the ratio is equal to $0$ because the numerator is $0$ and the denominator is greater than $0$, right?

Comment: Right, if you change "the limit of the ratio" to "the ratio". For $t$ close to $1$ the ratio equals $0$, because the numerator equals $0$ and the denomiator does not, right.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich So then the limit is $0$? I am asking because you said the limit is $1$ above.

Comment: Oh. That was just a typo, sorry. Yes, the limit is $0$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thank you.